# Unhide div with multiple checkboxes

Tags: javascript

I am having trouble cleaning up this javascript code. I need to add (n) number of checkboxes that unhide (n) number of div. This code works, but if I have 20 checkboxes is there a simpler way to write this code? Any help appreciated.

```
function Quantity() {
 // Get the checkbox
 var checkBox1 = document.getElementById("check1");
 var checkBox2 = document.getElementById("check2");
 var checkBox3 = document.getElementById("check3");
 var checkBox4 = document.getElementById("check4");
 // Get the output text
 var text1 = document.getElementById("q1");
 var text2 = document.getElementById("q2");
 var text3 = document.getElementById("q3");
 var text4 = document.getElementById("q4");
 // If the checkbox is checked, display the output text
 if (checkBox1.checked == true){
   text1.style.display = "block";
 } else {
   text1.style.display = "none";
 }
   if (checkBox2.checked == true){
   text2.style.display = "block";
 } else {
   text2.style.display = "none";
 }
    if (checkBox3.checked == true){
   text3.style.display = "block";
 } else {
   text3.style.display = "none";
 }
     if (checkBox4.checked == true){
   text4.style.display = "block";
 } else {
   text4.style.display = "none";
 }

}
```

Comment: You can use queryselectorAll and loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give each checkbox a data attribute stating which div is the target to be shown/hidden and give each checkbox a class. Then simply loop through each checkbox and add an event handler that will take that data attribute and hide/display it as needed.

```js
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll(".checkbox");

checkboxes.forEach(function(el){
   el.addEventListener("change",function(e){
      let target = document.querySelector(el.getAttribute("data-target"));
      target.style.display = (el.checked) ? "block" : "none";
  });
});
```

```css
.content-div{display:none;}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" data-target="#div1">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" data-target="#div2">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" data-target="#div3">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" data-target="#div4">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" data-target="#div5">

<div class="content-div" id="div1">1</div>
<div class="content-div" id="div2">2</div>
<div class="content-div" id="div3">3</div>
<div class="content-div" id="div4">4</div>
<div class="content-div" id="div5">5</div>
```

Or using your existing names

```
function Quantity(){
    var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']");
    checkboxes.forEach(function(el){
       let id = el.getAttribute("id").replace("check","");
       let target = document.querySelector("#q" + id);
       target.style.display = (el.checked) ? "block" : "none";
     });
}

Quantity();
```

Comment: Thank-you! This worked. Much appreciated.

Comment: I have an input inside the hidden divisions, how do I modify the code above to have then "required" when displayed and "not required" when hidden?

Answer (score 0):

In order to turn your code into something which supports a dynamic, undefined number of elements, you should implement a broader query selector and loop over the results.

In order to turn your existing code into something which works for different numbers of inputs, you can use the following code which is invoked like this `Quantity(5)` if there are 5 checkboxes.

```
function Quantity(numChecks) {
    for(var i = 1; i < numChecks + 1; i++) {
        // Get the checkbox
        // Will get check1, check2, check3 all the way up to numChecks
        var checkBox = document.getElementById("check" + i);

        // Get the output text
        // Will get q1, q2, q3 all the way up to numChecks
        var text = document.getElementById("q" + i);


        // If the checkbox is checked, display the output text
        if (checkBox.checked == true){
            text.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            text.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```